# import other ts files in visual studio

Tags: typescript

In my project, I am importing libraries and everything is loading and I am not getting any errors.

Now I have made few `ts` files for my project which are consuming the libraries that I have imported. This works by using `import`.

Now I want to use `BaseBundle.ts` in `Main.ts`. How can I do that?

This is what I have tried and have been unsuccessful.

1. `import BaseBundle = require("src/main/ts/bundles/BaseBundle");`
2. `import BaseBundle = require("bundles/BaseBundle");`
3. `/// <.reference path="bundles/BaseBundle.ts" />`
4. `/// <.reference path="src/main/ts/bundles/BaseBundle.ts" />`

`BaseBundle.ts` only has an interface name `BaseBundle`.
Every time I'm trying to access `BaseBundle` in `Main.ts`, I'm getting an error.

Please help with any suggestions or ideas

Comment: Please provide the error message

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I checked with your solution, but I am still getting an error.
The error is "Cannot find external module 'BaseBundle'."

Below is the code that I have written.

<code>/// <reference path="src/main/ts/bundles/BaseBundle.ts" />

<code>import BaseBundle = require("BaseBundle");

I am getting the above error on the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

Getting an answer here is hard without any error messages :[ But i'll try since i have not enough reputation to ask for further infos via comment..

> /// `<.reference path="src/main/ts/bundles/BaseBundle.ts" />`

try `<reference path="src/main/ts/bundles/BaseBundle.ts" />` as you use in Point 4 but without the '.'.

> Import BaseBundle = require("bundles/BaseBundle");

Should work while you are out of your class. Here is my approach:

```
    ///<reference path="./i1.ts" />

import i1 = require('i1');

class c1 implements i1.i1{
//import i1 = require('i1');

constructor() {

}

}
```

Note: My Interface is called i1. Now the only error i get is, that i have to implement my functions i defined in my interface.

So I have a approach like this and intellisense won't give me an error.

i1.ts:

```
export interface i1 {
fktn1();
fktn2();
}
```

c1.ts

```
///<reference path="./i1.ts" />

import i1 = require('i1');

class c1 implements i1.i1{
    //import i1 = require('i1');

    constructor() {

    }

    fktn1() {
        //interface function
    }

    fktn2() {
        // Interface function
    }

}
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-going-external

Hope that makes it more clear for you.

Edit:

Told just the half of the answer: In Visual Studio, go to Prject->YourWebProject-Settings->Typescript-Build and set your Modul System. I took 'AMD'.
[image: Here you can see what I mean]

Also be aware that you have to reference the BaseBundle-class within your variable BaseBundle

```
    ///<reference path="BaseBundle.ts"/> 

import BaseBundle = require('BaseBundle');

class blubb implements BaseBundle.BaseBundle {


}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I checked with your solution, but I am still getting an error.
The error is "Cannot find external module 'BaseBundle'."
Below is the code that I have written.
'code'
/// <reference path="src/main/ts/bundles/BaseBundle.ts" />

import BaseBundle = require("BaseBundle");
'code'

I am getting the above error on the import statement.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I checked with your solution, but I am still getting an error.
The error is "Cannot find external module 'BaseBundle'."

Below is the code that I have written.

<code>/// <reference path="src/main/ts/bundles/BaseBundle.ts" />

<code>import BaseBundle = require("BaseBundle");

I am getting the above error on the import statement.

Comment: I edited my answer. If there is still this error, please give us information on wich part of the code (e.g.: wrong reference-path, cannot find BaseBundle in require()) the error occurs.